# Cant Install Intel HAXM

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, intel, haxm

I have been using Intel HAXM before with no issues, however when Android Studio 2.0 released I reinstalled the IDE and it prompted me to install HAXM before starting the emulator. The installation went through (and still goes) successfully however Android Studio still says intel HAXM is not installed.

[image]
I also tried running the setup (intelhaxm-android.exe) manually from the SDK, but the GUI pops up and dissappears quickly.

I even tried running the setup available on Intel's [website](https://software.intel.com/en-us/android/articles/intel-hardware-accelerated-execution-manager) but the same happened.

haxm_check.exe says...
[image]

I am running...
[image]

and have no antivirus installed.

Comment: Update to 2.1, may have a luck.

Comment: Just updated to 2.1. No difference :(

Comment: Enable Virtualization on your BIOS, https://software.intel.com/en-us/android/articles/intel-hardware-accelerated-execution-manager-end-user-license-agreement  HAXM for Windows Zip version Accept and Install or try to update your Graphics.

Comment: Both graphics cards Intel HD 4600 & Nvidia GTX 870m updated to latest drivers. Cant find the option to enable virtualization in BIOS. However both Intel Processor Identification Utility and Microsoft's Hadrware Assisted Virtualization Detection Tool say virtualization is enabled.

Answer (score 0):

I had faced same issue. But actually there are no hardware issue. The point is  haxm installer is not executed by some reason. So, you have to extract .exe installer file with 7z program. then, there are x86, x86_64 installer... Maybe installer works fine.